# Cannot create connection in SQL Developer with new user added in PDB

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle18c

First of, I'm still new when it comes to Oracle DBs and how they tend to do stuff so please forgive if I'm failing to see something obvious. I spent around 5 hours troubleshooting following issue and can't seem to resolve it on my own. Would really appreciate any help I can get.

I'm running SQL Developer for Oracle XE 18c database on my personal PC, trying to learn APEX with it and I'm having issues creating connection to DB with new user, once new user is added. Relevant info:

1. Able to connect to database using New connection prompt > **sys** as SYSDBA / **password** or **system** / **password** [screenshot of successful test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwLGw.png)
2. Must change from CDB to PDB (in my case to XEPDB1 with ALTER SESSION) if I want to add user
3. If I try to add user either through SQL or GUI when in CDB - I get error ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name in oracle (meaning I have to switch to PDB - ok, no problem)
4. Once I switch to PDB - I am able to add user properly
5. User is simple name, simple pass, no way it can be missed, made 5-6 different accounts while trying, demo/demo, test/test, we'll use username: **master** / password: **masterkey** in this example
6. Once I try to create New connection > **master** / **masterkey** I get **Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied**, this is happening with every single user I created [logon denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxX07.png)
7. Same happens if I try logging through SQLPlus [sqlplus success for system user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIg9f.png)

All the tutorials, explanations and answers I found, make it so simple to log in with system > create new user > create new connection with that same user. Simple as that, but not me.
Now, I do see my created user under Other users section but I believe I should be able to have this user separately, as it's own connection, right?
[screenshot for that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMecx.png)

I will appreciate every help I can get. Let me know if you need any other configuration data.

`lsnrctl services` output:

````
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 09-MAY-2021 02:52:21

Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DESKTOP-LU84249)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "33a4c118d1384fc5842519d99267b5b7" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:13 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:13 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: DESKTOP-LU84249, pid: 7788>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DESKTOP-LU84249)(PORT=59728))
Service "xepdb1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:13 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully```
````

Comment: You need to use "service name" to connect to PDB. The user you created exists in PDB, not in CDB, since it's not "common user"

Comment: From your description, it seems that you know how to log into the CDB and from there to ALTER SESSION to switch to the PDB; but do you know how to connect (even as SYS) directly to the PDB? It should look something like this: `connect sys@xepdb1 as sysdba` - and then you will be asked for password, and you must give it (it's not the same as connecting to the CDB, where you can use OS authentication). You will connect to `xepdb1` as the newly created user the same way - as long as you granted `create session` to the user. First try this in SQL\*Plus, then we can discuss SQL Developer.

Comment: Also - looking at your Connection view screenshot from SQL Developer: as Sayan said already, use "Service name" instead of "SID" - the "Service name" is very likely `xepdb1`.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov - found service name to be XE, tried connecting using service name - same logon denied error.

Comment: Try service name `xepdb1`. XE is the service **ID** - it is incorrectly shown as "name" in some places (as far as I recall).

Comment: Service names XE or XEPDB1 (from what I managed to find, no other service name is mentioned) give same error logon denied when used instead of SID.

Comment: Regarding logging in to PDB directly, when trying command you provided I just get the HELP list, meaning it's not correct, I tried few other options but can't see to log on to XEPDB1 directly, logs me straight to CDB root.

Comment: Were you able to log on through SQL\*Plus? `connect master@xepdb1` and enter the password, see what happens.

Comment: @nickelodeon show us what does return the following command: `lsnrctl services`. Probably you just haven't added a service for your PDB

Comment: @mathguy- Nope, tried `connect master@xepdb1` and `connect sys@xepdb1 as sysdba` I just get sent list of commands to create proper syntax.
If I go `sqlplus connect` then for user-name enter: `master@xepdb1` or `sys@xepdb1 as sysdba` + `password` I get 5 sec delay before error ORA-12154 TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified. I'll be battling with this first thing tomorrow morning again, thanks for your effort so far.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov - edited my question with lsnrctl services output. Thanks.

Comment: ok, so try in sqlplus: `conn master/masterkey@//localhost:1521/xepdb1` and show the output

Comment: if it works, than you need to choose connect by `Service name` and enter `xepdb1` in that field and try it. And show screenshot if it fails

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov, mathguy - Thanks for your help, but I managed to resolve it today. How? Fricking reboot of my PC was needed. Once I reconnected back, I was able to connect with all users I created yesterday. Service name was indeed XEPDB1.
I created Oracle XE DB yesterday and stared working on this but looks like reboot is necessary for DB to work properly? Nevertheless, if it was something else I'm sure we'd be able to resolve it, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by rebooting PC. Database was installed few hours earlier and I didn't reboot PC ever since, even with everything else properly configured. Connected successfully using service name XEPDB1 (should be default for XE DBs).